# Asp.net Core Routing Equivalent

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, routes

Good afternoon, I have the following question in ASP.Net Core 5, I am looking for the equivalent of the following code that I made in asp.net MVC with .Net Framework.

This was configured in the App.start of the Application in Routing

```
        //Actualidad
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "actualidad",
        url: "actualidad",
        defaults: new { controller = "seccion", action = "detalle", id = 2 });
```

in .net Core the following format is used:

```
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "historias",
                pattern: "{controller=Podcast}/{action=seccion}/{id=?}");

        });
```

but I can't find a way to pass a value to the id by default.

Comment: if you have `int? id` as a parameter, you can have something like `PodcastID = id ?? 2` to get the same result. I realize it's not the answer, but could be a solution

Comment: what I want to do is set the id value to hard. in MVC I could assign the id as I comment in the code above but in .Net core it does not return the value of the ID in the controller

Answer (score 1):

you can use the same in net core

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
              pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

      endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                  name: "historian",
                  pattern: "seccion/{id=2}",
                  defaults: new { controller = "Podcast", action = "Seccion" });

            });
```

it will start from

```
public partial class PodcastController : Controller
{
   public IActionResult Seccion(int id)
    {
         // id will be 2
```

or you can try this url

```
http://localhost:xxx/seccion
```

it will go to seccion action with input parameter id=2

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Try to do this but in the controller the value of the id never gets. what should be 2

Comment: @DanielLazarte Sorry, it was a typo. Change name to default.

Comment: if I notice. but in the same way in the controller it does not return the value of the id

Comment: @DanielLazarte It will return in action Seccion. Controller doesn' t return anything

Comment: Yes of course. In the action section it should return the id = 2 but it does not

Comment: @DanielLazarte Action will not return anything. Just id will be 2. Put a breakpoint in the first line of the action

Comment: I think I did not express myself well, serge. I apologize. Correct the action does not return anything, when I put breakpoint in the id to evaluate the value it is always at 0

Comment: @DanielLazarte  I am sorry , but I tested it in Visual Studio and everything is working properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236791/discussion-between-daniel-lazarte-and-serge).

Comment: create a chat. could you help me? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236791/discussion-between-daniel-lazarte-and-serge